# How to predict custom image with PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Good evening everyone,
I'm trying to build multiple image classification with 4 classes with a custom Dataset
That's my model so Can someone please help me identify where the wrong because it always predicts class left at all images

```
class TingVGG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape: int, hidden_units: int, output_shape: int) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.conv_block1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=input_shape,out_channels=hidden_units,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=hidden_units, out_channels=hidden_units, kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )
        
        self.conv_block2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=hidden_units,out_channels=hidden_units,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=hidden_units, out_channels=hidden_units, kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )
        
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Flatten(), nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_units*32*32 ,out_features=output_shape))
        
        
    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor):
        x = self.conv_block1(x)
        #print(x.shape)
        x = self.conv_block2(x)
        #print(x.shape)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        #print(x.shape)
        return x
```

And that's my train and test function:

```
def train_step(model: torch.nn.Module,
               dataloader: DataLoader,
               loss_fn: torch.nn.Module,
               optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer,
               device=device
               ):
    # put the model into the train
    model.train()
    
    # Setup train loss and train accuracy values
    train_loss, train_acc = 0, 0
    
    # Loop through DataLoader and data batches
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
         # Send data to the target device
         X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
         
         # 1. forward pass
         y_pred = model(X) #output model logits
         
         # 2. Calculate the loss
         loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
         train_loss += loss.item()
         
         # 3. Optimize zero grad
         optimizer.zero_grad()
         
         # 4.Loss backward
         loss.backward()
         
         # 5.Optimzer step
         optimizer.step()
         
         # Calculate the accuracy metric
         y_pred_class = torch.argmax(torch.softmax(y_pred, dim=1), dim=1)
         train_acc += (y_pred_class ==y).sum().item()/len(y_pred)
    
    # Adjust metrics to get average loss and accuracy per batch
    train_loss = train_loss / len(dataloader)
    train_acc = train_acc / len(dataloader)
    return train_loss, train_acc


def test_step(model: torch.nn.Module,
               dataloader: DataLoader,
               loss_fn: torch.nn.Module,
               device=device
               ):
    # Put the model in eval mode
    model.eval()
    
    # Setup train loss and train accuracy values
    test_loss, test_acc = 0, 0
    
    # Turn on inference mode
    with torch.inference_mode():
        # Loop through DataLoader Batches
        for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
            # Send data to the target device
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
            
            # 1. forward pass
            test_pred_logits = model(X)
            
            # 2. Calculate the loss
            loss = loss_fn(test_pred_logits, y)
            test_loss += loss.item()
            
            # 3. Calculate the accuracy
            test_pred_labels = test_pred_logits.argmax(dim=1)
            test_acc += ((test_pred_labels == y).sum().item() / len(test_pred_labels))
            
    # Adjust metrics to get average loss and accuracy per batch
    test_loss = test_loss / len(dataloader)
    test_acc = test_acc / len(dataloader)
    return test_loss, test_acc


def train(model: torch.nn.Module,
          train_dataloader: DataLoader,
          test_dataloader: DataLoader,
          optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer,
          loss_fn: torch.nn.Module = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(),
          epochs: int = 10,
          device = device):
    # 2. Create empty results dictionary
    results = {"train_loss": [],
               "train_acc": [],
               "test_loss": [],
               "test_acc": []}
    
    # 3. Loop through training and testing steps for a number of epochs
    for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs)):
        train_loss, train_acc = train_step(model= model, dataloader= train_dataloader,loss_fn=loss_fn, optimizer=optimizer, device=device)
        test_loss, test_acc = test_step(model= model, dataloader=test_dataloader,loss_fn=loss_fn, device=device)
        
        # 4. Print out what's happening
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch +1} | "
            f"train_loss: {train_loss:.4f} | "
            f"train_acc: {train_acc:.4f} | "
            f"test_loss: {test_loss:.4f} | "
            f"test_acc: {test_acc:.4f}")
        
        # 5. Update the results dictionary
        results["train_loss"].append(train_loss)
        results["train_acc"].append(train_acc)
        results["test_loss"].append(test_loss)
        results["test_acc"].append(test_acc)
        
    # 6. return the results at the end of the epoches
    return results


# Set random seed
torch.manual_seed(42)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(42)

# Set number of epoches
NUM_EPOCHS = 20

# Create and initialize of TinyVGG
model_0 = TingVGG(input_shape=1, # Number of channels in the input image (c, h, w) -> 3
                  hidden_units=20,
                  output_shape=len(train_data.classes)).to(device)

# Setup the loss function and optimizer
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params= model_0.parameters(),
                             lr= 0.001)

# Start the timer
start_time = timer()

# Train model 0
model_0_results = train(model= model_0,
                        train_dataloader= train_dataloader_simple,
                        test_dataloader= test_dataloader_simple,
                        optimizer= optimizer,
                        loss_fn= loss_fn,
                        epochs= NUM_EPOCHS
                        )

# End the timer and print the results
end_time = timer()
print(f"Total training time: {end_time - start_time: .3f} seconds")
```

And I saved the model and loaded with that:

```
PATH='Model_3.pth'
torch.save(model_0, PATH)
model = torch.load('Model_3.pth', map_location='cpu')
```

And that's how to make the prediction:

```
images_path = r'Rotation_Images\train\180'
class_names = ['180', 'left', 'right', 'zero']


for img in os.listdir(images_path):
    
    start_time =  timer()
    
    # Reads a file using pillow
    PIL_image = PIL.Image.open(images_path + "/" + img)

    # Convert to numpy array
    numpy_array = np.array(PIL_image)

    # Convert to PyTorch tensor
    tensor = torch.from_numpy(numpy_array)


    tensor = tensor.unsqueeze(0).type(torch.float32)

    tensor_image = tensor / 255. 
    
    # Create transform pipleine to resize image
    custom_image_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((128, 128)),
    ])

    # Transform target image
    custom_image_transformed = custom_image_transform(tensor_image)
    
    model.eval()
    with torch.inference_mode():
        # Add an extra dimension to image
        custom_image_transformed_with_batch_size = custom_image_transformed.unsqueeze(dim=0)      
        
        # Make a prediction on image with an extra dimension
        custom_image_pred = model(custom_image_transformed_with_batch_size.to(device))
        
        # Convert logits -> prediction probabilities (using torch.softmax() for multi-class classification)
        custom_image_pred_probs = torch.softmax(custom_image_pred, dim=1)
        # Convert prediction probabilities -> prediction labels
        custom_image_pred_label = torch.argmax(custom_image_pred_probs, dim=1)
        # Find the predicted label
        
        custom_image_pred_class = class_names[custom_image_pred_label.cpu()]
```

Sorry If I seemed stuped It's my 2nd weak at studying pytorch

Comment: is your model training well? Does your loss function go down as it should, and accuracy up ? are your images diverse (containing all classes) ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă sorry for late (the loss and ACC = Epoch: 20 | train_loss: 0.0021 | train_acc: 1.0000 | test_loss: 1.2065 | test_acc: 0.8828) .. and containing all classes yeh

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă I guess the wrong here conv_blocks I added the conv2d layers wrong ?

Comment: at a quick glance, I don't spot anything wrong with your conv2d layers. I think your model might be overfitting. Check that your dataloder is generating all images. And you should be doing multiple epochs over your dataset, and output the loss/acc at every batch, not just at the end. If you can get 100% acc in just 1 epch, something is fishy with the data